# Adding clients to a list in Erlang

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, tuples

so I am writing a basic server that clients can connect to. I'm testing it with telnet, but my issue is how I store my clients in a list, so I could then print out who is connected to the server. I've tried using the ++ operator on a list that stores clients, but I keep getting a process error.

Here is my code so far:

```
cell_process()->
    io:fwrite("In cell~n"),
    {ok,Listening_socket} = gen_tcp:listen(21,
                                           [binary,
                                            {backlog,5},
                                            {active,false},
                                            {packet,line}]),
    loop(Listening_socket).

loop(Listening_socket)->
    case gen_tcp:accept(Listening_socket) of
        {ok,Client_socket} ->

            gen_tcp:send(Client_socket, "Hello, what is your name?"),
            {_,Name} = gen_tcp:recv(Client_socket,0),
            gen_tcp:send(Client_socket, "Hello, "),
            gen_tcp:send(Client_socket, Name),
            io:fwrite([Name]),
            spawn(fun()-> client_loop(Client_socket) end),
            loop(Listening_socket);

        {error,Why}->io:fwrite("Error: "),
                     io:fwrite([Why])
    end.

client_loop(Client_socket)->
    case gen_tcp:recv(Client_socket,0) of
        {ok,Message}-> gen_tcp:send(Client_socket,Message),
                       %% code not yet implemented here
                       client_loop(Client_socket);

        {error,Why}-> io:fwrite("Error: ~s~n",[Why]),
                      gen_tcp:close(Client_socket)
    end.
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep a trace of connected clients you have to add a variable to the loop function, and store any relevant information in a Clients list as you suggest.

```
cell_process()->
    io:fwrite("In cell~n"),
    {ok,Listening_socket} = gen_tcp:listen(21,
                                           [binary,
                                            {backlog,5},
                                            {active,false},
                                            {packet,line}]),
    loop(Listening_socket,[]). %% initial Clients list is empty

loop(Listening_socket,Clients)->
    case gen_tcp:accept(Listening_socket) of
        {ok,Client_socket} ->

            gen_tcp:send(Client_socket, "Hello, what is your name?"),
            {_,Name} = gen_tcp:recv(Client_socket,0),
            gen_tcp:send(Client_socket, "Hello, "),
            gen_tcp:send(Client_socket, Name),
            io:fwrite([Name]),
            Pid = spawn(fun()-> client_loop(Client_socket) end),
            loop(Listening_socket,[{Pid,Client_socket,Name}|Clients]);
```

%% add new Client to the lists **But see my comment**

```
        {error,Why}->io:fwrite("Error: "),
                     io:fwrite([Why])
    end.

client_loop(Client_socket)->
    case gen_tcp:recv(Client_socket,0) of
        {ok,Message}-> gen_tcp:send(Client_socket,Message),
                       %% code not yet implemented here
                       client_loop(Client_socket);

        {error,Why}-> io:fwrite("Error: ~s~n",[Why]),
                      gen_tcp:close(Client_socket)
    end.
```

Comment: It is not the right place to store the Client list, because you will have to manage the client who are dying, either with links or monitor, so you need a receive block, incompatible with the socket listening. So I think that you should add a server to manage this list, which role is to listen the messages sent each time a new Client is launched, monitor the Clients, answer to the admin when he want to know the Client list ...

Comment: This works great thank you! The only other issue I am having now is how to print the list of clients to the shell, I've tried io:fwrite, but that crashes the process.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion:

```
loop(Listening_socket, ClientList)->
    case gen_tcp:accept(Listening_socket) of
        {ok,Client_socket} ->
            gen_tcp:send(Client_socket, "Hello, what is your name?"),
            {_,Name} = gen_tcp:recv(Client_socket,0),
            gen_tcp:send(Client_socket, "Hello, "),
            gen_tcp:send(Client_socket, Name),
            io:fwrite([Name]),
            spawn(fun()-> client_loop(Client_socket) end),
            loop(Listening_socket, [Client_socket | ClientList]);

        {error,Why}->io:fwrite("Error: "),
                     io:fwrite([Why])
    end.
```

A better solution would be to have a `state` record where you store all the vars you need (in this case, Listening_socket and ClientList) and loop with that `state`.